# Logstash: NameError: undefined local variable or method `dotfile' for # <AwesomePrint::Inspector:0x77011d93>>

Tags: amazon-ec2, logstash, amazon-linux

I'm migrating a logstash into a EC2 instance.

It's running a AmazonLinux.

By the command `tail -f /var/log/logstash/logstash-plain.log`

I'm getting a the follow log cycling/repeating

```
2017-12-20T15:30:24,742][INFO ][logstash.modules.scaffold] Initializing module {:module_name=>"netflow", :directory=>"/usr/share/logstash/modules/netflow/configuration"}
[2017-12-20T15:30:24,745][INFO ][logstash.modules.scaffold] Initializing module {:module_name=>"fb_apache", :directory=>"/usr/share/logstash/modules/fb_apache/configuration"}
[2017-12-20T15:30:27,342][INFO ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch] Elasticsearch pool URLs updated {:changes=>{:removed=>[], :added=>[https://search-ivendas-sz2q3f573vro6xlncwjnvzbf2m.us-east-1.es.amazonaws.com:443/]}}
[2017-12-20T15:30:27,343][INFO ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch] Running health check to see if an Elasticsearch connection is working {:healthcheck_url=>https://search-ivendas-sz2q3f573vro6xlncwjnvzbf2m.us-east-1.es.amazonaws.com:443/, :path=>"/"}
[2017-12-20T15:30:28,040][WARN ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch] Restored connection to ES instance {:url=>"https://search-ivendas-sz2q3f573vro6xlncwjnvzbf2m.us-east-1.es.amazonaws.com:443/"}
[2017-12-20T15:30:28,175][INFO ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch] Using mapping template from {:path=>nil}
[2017-12-20T15:30:28,185][INFO ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch] Attempting to install template {:manage_template=>{"template"=>"logstash-*", "version"=>50001, "settings"=>{"index.refresh_interval"=>"5s"}, "mappings"=>{"_default_"=>{"_all"=>{"enabled"=>true, "norms"=>false}, "dynamic_templates"=>[{"message_field"=>{"path_match"=>"message", "match_mapping_type"=>"string", "mapping"=>{"type"=>"text", "norms"=>false}}}, {"string_fields"=>{"match"=>"*", "match_mapping_type"=>"string", "mapping"=>{"type"=>"text", "norms"=>false, "fields"=>{"keyword"=>{"type"=>"keyword", "ignore_above"=>256}}}}}], "properties"=>{"@timestamp"=>{"type"=>"date", "include_in_all"=>false}, "@version"=>{"type"=>"keyword", "include_in_all"=>false}, "geoip"=>{"dynamic"=>true, "properties"=>{"ip"=>{"type"=>"ip"}, "location"=>{"type"=>"geo_point"}, "latitude"=>{"type"=>"half_float"}, "longitude"=>{"type"=>"half_float"}}}}}}}}
[2017-12-20T15:30:28,201][INFO ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch] New Elasticsearch output {:class=>"LogStash::Outputs::ElasticSearch", :hosts=>["//search-ivendas-sz2q3f573vro6xlncwjnvzbf2m.us-east-1.es.amazonaws.com:443"]}
[2017-12-20T15:30:28,385][INFO ][logstash.pipeline        ] Starting pipeline {"id"=>"main", "pipeline.workers"=>2, "pipeline.batch.size"=>125, "pipeline.batch.delay"=>5, "pipeline.max_inflight"=>250}
[2017-12-20T15:30:29,298][INFO ][logstash.pipeline        ] Pipeline main started
[2017-12-20T15:30:29,502][INFO ][logstash.agent           ] Successfully started Logstash API endpoint {:port=>9600}
[2017-12-20T15:30:29,979][FATAL][logstash.runner          ] An unexpected error occurred! {:error=>#<NameError: undefined local variable or method `dotfile' for #<AwesomePrint::Inspector:0x18bafa48>>, :backtrace=>["/usr/share/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/awesome_print-1.8.0/lib/awesome_print/inspector.rb:163:in `merge_custom_defaults!'", "/usr/share/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/awesome_print-1.8.0/lib/awesome_print/inspector.rb:50:in `initialize'", "/usr/share/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/awesome_print-1.8.0/lib/awesome_print/core_ext/kernel.rb:9:in `ai'", "/usr/share/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/logstash-codec-rubydebug-3.0.5/lib/logstash/codecs/rubydebug.rb:39:in `encode_default'", "org/jruby/RubyMethod.java:120:in `call'", "/usr/share/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/logstash-codec-rubydebug-3.0.5/lib/logstash/codecs/rubydebug.rb:35:in `encode'", "/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/codecs/base.rb:50:in `multi_encode'", "org/jruby/RubyArray.java:1613:in `each'", "/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/codecs/base.rb:50:in `multi_encode'", "/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/outputs/base.rb:90:in `multi_receive'", "/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/output_delegator_strategies/single.rb:15:in `multi_receive'", "org/jruby/ext/thread/Mutex.java:149:in `synchronize'", "/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/output_delegator_strategies/single.rb:14:in `multi_receive'", "/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/output_delegator.rb:49:in `multi_receive'", "/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/pipeline.rb:434:in `output_batch'", "org/jruby/RubyHash.java:1342:in `each'", "/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/pipeline.rb:433:in `output_batch'", "/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/pipeline.rb:381:in `worker_loop'", "/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/pipeline.rb:342:in `start_workers'"]}
```

I did installed the missing plugins, before I was getting another errors.

Is there someway to get more details about the problem ?

What am I missing ?

Comment: if you solved your issue please post the fix !

Answer (score 1):

This is an [issue](https://github.com/logstash-plugins/logstash-output-stdout/issues/11) with awesome-print plugin for rubydebug codec. set the HOME env variable (`export HOME=<path_to_aprc_file>`) which will be used to load .aprc configuration required by plugin. Refer [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/117467/how-to-permanently-set-environmental-variables) to persist this env variable.

Comment: what's the purpose of this aprc file ?

Comment: @FAjir, .aprc file where we can specify custom defaults for awesome-print plugin.

Comment: where is this aprc file?